# Update Data Of RecyclerView Of Fragment Inside ViewPager Of Activity From DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` inside a `fragment`, The fragment is inside a view pager and view pager is obviously in activity. I have `DialogFragment` with some edittext from where I am adding data in `SQLite`. The Dialogfragment is opened by FAB inside activity, after adding data in SQLite How Can I update data in recyclerview.

> **(The Dialog Fragment) AddNotesFragment.java**

```
 toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.save_note: {
                    if (checkForInput(mNoteEditText.getText().toString(),mNoteTitleEditText.getText().toString())) {
                        Note note = new Note(0,mNoteTitleEditText.getText().toString(),mNoteEditText.getText().toString(),null);
                         createNote(note);
                         mListener.onComplete(note);
                         dismiss();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



 private long createNote(Note note) {
    // inserting note in db and getting
    // newly inserted note id
    SQLiteHelper db = new SQLiteHelper(getContext());
    return db.insertNote(note);
}
```

> **(Fragment With RecylerView) NotesFragment.java**

```
   db = new SQLiteHelper(getContext());
    notesList.addAll(db.getAllNotes());

    mAdapter = new NotesAdapter(getContext(), notesList,getActivity(),getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

> **(Activity With ViewPager) MainActivity.java**

```
   mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    final AddNotesFragment  addNotesFragment = new AddNotesFragment();
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    final SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(CenterActivity.this);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
```

How Can I Update The Data Of RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update data using **Interface** or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)